# Using a block of R code in SQL. Need to insert R dataframes into 2 separate temp tables

Tags: sql

I am using a SQL stored procedure to create two temp tables, run a block of R code which produces 2 dataframes and can only figure out how to insert into one temp table.

INSERT INTO #TmpRes with (tablock)
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
@language = N'R'
,@script = N'

The above works.

How do I add the second temp table called #TmpOut?